# sending a put request inside a mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I have a mailer:

```
To activate your account, please click on the link below:
<%= link_to "Activate Account", activation_url(@user.auth_token) %>
```

and an activations_controller:

```
class ActivationsController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @user = User.find_by(:auth_token, params[:id])

    @user.update(member: true)
    flash[:notice] = "Your account is now activated."
    redirect_to login_path
 end
```

end

How can I issue a put command in my mailer?

Comment: The link_to produces a GET Activations#update, so I was wondering how to make it call a PUT.

Comment: You can make it POST when you turn it into a form and target the form submit action to the URL. I dont think PUT is supported by browsers.

Comment: Did you tried ``link_to "Activate Account", activation_url(@user.auth_token), method: :put``?

Comment: yes...it doesn't work.